# Description Not Appearing in Calendar Events from Email Markup Schema Confirmation Emails

Tags: google-schemas

We are currently facing an issue wherein the "Description" field is not displaying in Calendar events created through confirmation emails utilizing the Email Markup Schema.

Here is the current Email Markup Schema:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
    "reservationNumber": "12d2ds2",
    "reservationId": "12d2ds2",
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
    "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Lisa"
    },
    "provider": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison"
    },
    "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison",
        "startDate": "2023-11-21T19:00+05:30",
        "endDate": "2023-11-21T23:00+05:30",
        "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
        "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventScheduled",
        "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
                "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
                "postalCode": "19019",
                "addressRegion": "PA",
                "addressCountry": "US"
            }
        },
        "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
        "performer": {
            "@type": "PerformingGroup",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison"
        },
        "organizer": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
        }
    }
}
    </script>
```

Please review the provided schema and advise if any modifications are needed to rectify the absence of the Description in the Calendar events?
I appreciate your prompt attention to this matter and look forward to your guidance on resolving this issue.